# addClass to all unselected li when one li is selected// also adding a flip animation

Tags: jquery, html, toggle, addclass, flip

I have a list of items with a toggle to open a div underneath when one of the li are clicked. I also have it styled so to addClass to the selected li image when that div is open. I'd like to now add something to my jquery so that when you click on the li and the div opens, all other li's blur. I added ".blur-logo" to my css, but can't figure out how to do this in my jquery.

I'd also like to incorporate code to flip the image in the li when selected, if someone's also able to help with that!

```
<ul>
<li><a class="artist-logo" href="#artist-looka"><img src="images/looka-black-circle.png"></a></li>
<li><a class="artist-logo" href="#artist-sremedy"><img src="images/sremedy-black-circle.png"></a></li>
 <li><a class="artist-logo" href="#artist-hyperbit"><img src="images/hyperbit-black-circle.png"></a></li>
 </ul>

 <div id="artist-looka" class="artist-box">
 </div>
 <div id="artist-sremedy" class="artist-box">
 </div>
 <div id="artist-hyperbit" class="artist-box">
 </div>             




$(function(){

$("nav ul li a").click(function() {
var navId= $(this).attr("href");
$("body, html").animate({scrollTop: $(navId).offset().top},500);
return false;
});

// Add class to each link on click. Remove when new link clicked
$('#togglemenu1 ul li a').click(function(){
  $('nav ul li a').removeClass('selected');
  $(this).toggleClass('selected');
});
});    


$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".artist-box").hide();
    $(".artist-logo").click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        // get the clicked element
        var clicked = $(this);
        // get the selected element
        var taggedWithSelect = $('.selected-artist');  
        // get the corresponding divs
        var clickPartner = $(clicked.attr('href'));
        var selectPartner = $(taggedWithSelect.attr('href'));
        // we either want to close this one or open this one and close any others
        // if this one is open, it should be tagged with select
        if( clicked.hasClass('selected-artist') ) {
            clicked.removeClass('selected-artist');
        } else {
            clicked.addClass('selected-artist');
            taggedWithSelect.removeClass('selected-artist');
            selectPartner.slideToggle();
        }
        clickPartner.slideToggle();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

First add a class to each list tag (e.g., li-artist-logo). Then add an id for each list tag and onclick for the a href. Then, try using fadeTo for each of the artist-logo classes and a separate fadeTo for the id of the clicked li:

```
<li id="li1" class="li-artist-logo"><a class="artist-logo" href="#artist-looka" onclick="FadeFunction('li1')">   
<img src="images/looka-black-circle.png"></a></li>

function FadeFunction(id) {
    $(".li-artist-logo").fadeTo(1, 0.0, function () {
        $("#" + id).fadeTo(1, 1.0);
    });
}
```

Comment: I'm not really understanding how this one would work.